# Syntax error with aliases in PostgreSQL subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to SQL and trying to do a certain query in which I need two subqueries. I have to give them aliases, but when I do it says:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "as"
```

But I don't see anything wrong in the syntax. I'm having a lot of trouble with this kind of queries and I don't find much information or examples. Would you help me?

```
Select
    ...
from
    turno,
    (select * from
        (
            select 
                ...
             from 
                accion
            where
                accion.tipo = 4 or accion.tipo = 5
        ) as part1
        union
        (
            select 
                ...
             from 
                accion
            where
                accion.tipo <> 4 and accion.tipo <> 5
        ) as part2
    ) as accion
where 
    ...
;
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Select
    ...
from
    turno,
    (select * from
        (
            select 
                ...
             from 
                accion
            where
                accion.tipo = 4 or accion.tipo = 5
         union
            select 
                ...
             from 
                accion
            where
                accion.tipo <> 4 and accion.tipo <> 5
        ) as part1_2
    ) as accion
where 
    ...
;
```

Comment: Obviously, it works now. I have tried all posible ways to put it that came to my mind, I guess I haven't got SQL yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You have more query levels than necessary and mix them up. Try:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   turno,
      ( 
    SELECT ...
    FROM   accion
    WHERE  accion.tipo = 4 OR accion.tipo = 5

    UNION
    SELECT ...
    FROM   accion
    WHERE  accion.tipo <> 4 AND accion.tipo <> 5
   ) AS accion
WHERE ...
```

Better:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   turno
JOIN   (    
    SELECT ...
    FROM   accion
    WHERE  accion.tipo = 4 OR accion.tipo = 5

    UNION
    SELECT ...
    FROM   accion
    WHERE  accion.tipo <> 4 AND accion.tipo <> 5
   ) AS accion ON <join condition>
WHERE ...
```

Better yet, simplify to:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   turno
JOIN   (    
    SELECT ...
    FROM   accion
    WHERE  accion.tipo  = 4
       OR  accion.tipo  = 5
       OR (accion.tipo <> 4 AND accion.tipo <> 5)
   ) AS accion ON <join condition>
WHERE ...
```

Yields the same result, only faster & simpler.

The conditions qualify all rows (except `a.tipo IS NULL`) in `accion`. So in this particular case you can further simplify:

```
SELECT ...
FROM   turno
JOIN   accion a ON a.tipo IS NOT NULL AND <join condition>
WHERE  ...
```

But that's probably due to over-simplification of the problem, right?

This last example also demonstrates how the keyword `AS` is just noise in this context.

Comment: I can't use the last options since I need to make diferent things on the select for each one of the two subqueries. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @jesusiniesta: Depending on what you actually need, you might get it cheaper with a CASE statement.

Comment: Brandstetter: Thanks, I didn't know that. It's great for those two subqueries (there is another third one I cannot put there, but it's a great help).